# vertically center div in page with sticky footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm trying to vertically align a div in IE11. I have tried to use the answer of @billbad [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

The difference between my axample and many other examples on the internet is that they don't use a sticky footer and I think is what is causing me the error.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="art-header"></div>
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="middle-container text-center">
        <div class="contner">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-center" (click)="addLine()">Primary</button>
            <ul>
              <li *ngFor="let line of name" >
              {{ line }}
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="rmpm-footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
</div>
</div>
```

A part of **CSS**

```
 .contner {
  min-height: 242px;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 604px;
  padding-top:10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  transition: max-height .4s;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

  margin-top: 40px;
}
.middle-container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;

}
.outer-container {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Actually the div is not well centred and footer height is resized. that's not what I'm looking for.

**Expected behavior** is when I add lines the div still centred then footer get down when the div became bigger than initial page height.

I have created a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcenter-sticky-footer?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) you can check directly my code there.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using `margin-top`instead `display: table-cell`

```
.middle-container {
  margin-top: 40%;
}
```

Comment: Without changing anything else ?

Comment: Yes, the problem here is that foot div is affecting the total heigt then you cando the following `center = 40%  foot = 10%   center = center-foot`  finally you will have exactly you center in 30 or 35 it depends of the size of foot div

Comment: If you can provide an example that would be great